# Coaxial cable with compound dielectric

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, conductors, dielectric

I'm trying to solve a problem from Reitz and Milford's Foundations of Electromagnetic Theory (3rd ed, problem 4-8), and don't know how to start:

A coaxial cable of circular cross section has a compound dielectric. The inner conductor has an outside radius $ a $; this is surrounded by a dielectric sheath of dielectric constant $ K_1 $ and of outer radius $ b $. Next comes another dielectric sheath of dielectric constant $ K_2 $ and outer radius $ c $. If a potential difference $ V_0 $ is imposed between the conductors, calculate the fields $ \vec{E}(\vec{r}), \, \vec{D}(\vec{r}), \, \vec{P}(\vec{r}) $ in both dielectrics.

I'm assuming I have to use the solution to Laplace's equation in cylindrical coordinates, but I'm not sure about how to use the border conditions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Well, solved it by myself after a couple of hours, so I'm posting the solution just in case someone happens to have the same problem:

Let $ Q $ be the charge on a length $ l $ of the inner conductor. Applying Gauss's Law to that piece of cable:
$$ \oint \vec{D} \cdot d\vec{a} = D 2 \pi r l = Q \implies D = \frac{Q}{2 \pi r l}. $$ By definition, $ \vec{D} = \varepsilon_0 \kappa \vec{E} $, so $$ E_1 = \frac{Q}{2 \pi \varepsilon_0 \kappa_1 l r }, \,  (a < r < b), $$ $$ E_2 = \frac{Q}{2 \pi \varepsilon_0 \kappa_2 l r}, \, (b < r < c). $$

There is a potential difference $ V_0 $ between the conductors, so $$ V_0 = \int_{a}^{b} \left( \frac{Q}{2 \pi \varepsilon_0 \kappa_1 l} \right) \frac{dr}{r} + \int_{b}^{c} \left( \frac{Q}{2 \pi \varepsilon_0 \kappa_2 l} \right) \frac{dr}{r} = \frac{Q}{2 \pi \varepsilon_0 l} \left[ \frac{1}{\kappa_1} \ln \left( \frac{b}{a} \right) + \frac{1}{\kappa_2} \ln \left( \frac{c}{b} \right) \right]. $$  $$ \implies Q = \frac{2 \pi \varepsilon_0 l V_0}{\frac{1}{\kappa_1} \ln \left( \frac{b}{a} \right) + \frac{1}{\kappa_2} \ln \left( \frac{c}{b} \right)} = \frac{2 \pi \varepsilon_0 l V_0 \kappa_1 \kappa_2}{\kappa_2 \ln \left( \frac{b}{a} \right) + \kappa_1 \ln \left( \frac{c}{b} \right)}. $$
Using $ \sigma = \dfrac{Q}{2 \pi r l} $, we get: $$ \vec{D} = \left( \frac{\varepsilon_0 V_0 \kappa_1 \kappa_2}{\kappa_2 \ln \left( \frac{b}{a} \right) + \kappa_1 \ln \left( \frac{c}{b} \right)} \right) \frac{1}{r} \hat{e_r}, $$ and $$ \vec{D}_1 = \vec{D}_2 = \vec{D}. $$

As $ \vec{D} = \varepsilon_0 \kappa \vec{E} $, we get: $ \vec{E}_1= \dfrac{\vec{D}_1}{\varepsilon_0 \kappa_1}, \, \vec{E}_2 = \dfrac{\vec{D}_2}{\varepsilon_0 \kappa_2}: $

$$ \vec{E}_1 = \left( \frac{\kappa_2 V_0}{\kappa_2 \ln \left( \frac{b}{a} \right) + \kappa_1 \ln \left( \frac{c}{b} \right)} \right) \frac{1}{r} \hat{e_r}, $$ $$ \vec{E}_2 = \left( \frac{\kappa_1 V_0}{\kappa_2 \ln \left( \frac{b}{a} \right) + \kappa_1 \ln \left( \frac{c}{b} \right)} \right) \frac{1}{r} \hat{e_r}. $$

Finally, $ \vec{P} = \vec{D} - \varepsilon_0 \vec{E}: $

$$ \vec{P}_1 = \frac{(\kappa_1 -1) \varepsilon_0 \kappa_2 V_0}{\kappa_2 \ln \left( \frac{b}{a} \right) + \kappa_1 \ln \left( \frac{c}{b} \right)} \frac{1}{r} \hat{e_r}, $$ $$ \vec{P}_2 = \frac{(\kappa_2 -1) \varepsilon_0 \kappa_1 V_0}{\kappa_2 \ln \left( \frac{b}{a} \right) + \kappa_1 \ln \left( \frac{c}{b} \right)} \frac{1}{r} \hat{e_r}. $$

I hope I haven't made any mistakes. If anyone finds something please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

thanks a lot for sharing you answer! i've repeated the calculations using the same reasoning and ended up on the same answer but with a different sign ($(1-k)$ instead of $(k-1)$)... that came from the convention on the potential expression ... therefore nothing to worry.

But i think that it was defined an unnecessary (but maybe useful) parameter $\sigma$, that caused me some confusion. So if someone else is confused, remember that's not essential.

PS: Posting this as an answer instead of a comment because i don't have 15 reputation things ...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/414951)